# Removing a column of data from a matrix based on standard deviation of the row in R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a large data matrix, an example of which is below:

```
                row 1/col 1         row 1/col 2         row 1/col 3
 [1,]             855.815             749.574             754.950
 [2,]             855.718             749.496             755.004
 [3,]             855.846             749.359             754.910
 [4,]             855.746             749.299             754.795
 [5,]             855.805             749.421             754.883
```

I am trying to remove columns where the value of the first row is above or below one standard deviation away from the mean of the whole first row, using this code:

```
library(matrixStats)
x = data[,-1] > (rowMeans(data[,-1]) + rowSds(data[,-1]))
y = data[,-1] < (rowMeans(data[,-1]) - rowSds(data[,-1]))
subset(df2, !(x | y))
```

But this returns the following error when applied to my dataset:

```
Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

As I understand it, R has expanded this to read:

```
subset(df2, !(data[,-1] > (rowMeans(data[,-1]) + rowSds(data[,-1]))|data[,-1] < (rowMeans(data[,-1]) - rowSds(data[,-1]))))
```

and that the logical argument is simply too long. Is there something I am missing? I am inexperienced with R and sure there are neater ways to do this, but from what I have read I thought subset would be most useful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example

Comment: Also,  when you use a function from a package that is not part of base R, it is helpful to indicate that.  In this case, by starting your code with `library(matrixStats)`

Comment: G5W - I have started my code with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df <- as.matrix(read.table(text='C1 C2 C3
                 [1,]             855.815             749.574             754.950
                 [2,]             855.718             749.496             755.004
                 [3,]             855.846             749.359             754.910
                 [4,]             855.746             749.299             754.795
                 [5,]             855.805             749.421             754.883', header=TRUE))

library(matrixStats)
df[,which(abs(df[1,] - rowMeans(df)[1]) < rowSds(df)[1])]

#      C2      C3
#[1,] 749.574 754.950
#[2,] 749.496 755.004
#[3,] 749.359 754.910
#[4,] 749.299 754.795
#[5,] 749.421 754.883
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - that works perfectly for the data I shared as an example. However, when I apply it to my whole dataset and use dim() to see if columns have been removed, it remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, I was being idiotic - thank you for your help!